# Show two countries in Google Visualization: Geochart

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I want to show a map with two countries near each others, let's say USA and CANADA. As far as I can see, google allows me show either, the world, a zone(with many countries: eg North America), Region, or a country, but what I want actually to see is two adjacent countries.

Comment: If the GeoCharts do not have a map that corresponds to what you want, you would have to make your own map.  The only example of doing this that I know of is on the [Visualization API's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/KVGu--jjUpk/L3yTtnmFU4kJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not possible. one way to do that is to display the two countries seperatly then play with the DOM  to make them close to each other

Comment: I manage to solve this issue but displaying the two maps of the two countries, and then play with the jquery and css to make the two makes stay next to each others. It is not the best solution, but it was the only things I could do